# Make a Bouncing Ball with Canvas in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I make the ball start in an upwards motion?

I am super lost here and have tried to many things to mention and I know I am missing something simple.

I know this is the part of the code that I need to change, and that it has to do with the if statement for x, but that is far as I have gotten.

```
function update() {
    x += 1;
    y += yspeed;
    yspeed += gravity;
    if ( y >= context.canvas.height)
    {
        yspeed *= -1;
    }
    if ( x <= 0 || x >= context.canvas.width)
    {
        x = (x + context.canvas.width) % context.canvas.width;
    }
  }
```

Right now the ball starts out bouncing downward.  How do I change it to starting out bouncing upward?

Comment: Here is the full code, if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

**yspeed** determines the vertical speed of your ball - and it must be defined somewhere. Try changing it to a negative value like -10. What it actually pulls it down to the ground is **gravity**.

Here's an example [Hit 'Run code snippet' to see it in action]:

```js
var gravity = 1;
var yspeed = -10;
var x = 10;
var y = 50;
document.getElementById("ball").style.left = x + "px";
document.getElementById("ball").style.top = y + "px";

function loop() {
  document.getElementById("ball").style.left = x + "px";
  document.getElementById("ball").style.top = y + "px";
  x += 1;
  y += yspeed;
  yspeed += gravity;
}
var interval = setInterval(loop, 60);
```

```html
<svg height="20" width="20" id="ball" style="position:relative">
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="red" />
</svg>
```